Uniqueness of vector on a inner product space proof
I’m stuck on the following problem, only on part (b)

My idea was to start the proof by contradiction, supposing that there are two vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ which are unique, as well as using the substitution  $u=v_1 - v_2$, but i can’t seem to get anywhere. All help is appreciated

Well, if $\langle u,v_1\rangle=\langle u, v_2\rangle$ for all $u\in V$, what does this imply?

... or ... $0 = f(\hat{e}_i) - f(\hat{e}_i) =  \langle \hat{e}_i, v_1 \rangle - \langle \hat{e}_i, v_2 \rangle = \langle \hat{e}_i, v_1 - v_2 \rangle$ and none of the $\hat{e}_i$ (the members of the orthonormal basis in part (a)) are zero vectors, so ...

Also, note that if $f \neq 0$ then $\dim \ker f = n-1$, so $\ker f$ has a basis of $n-1$ vectors. Now pick any point in $(\ker f)^c$.
